# ColumnSliceIterator with MultigetSliceQuery

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

I am looking for examples of ColumnSliceIterator with MultigetSliceQuery. I dont find any? Any suggestions?

I found many examples of SliceQuery but there we can mention only one key. I am looking  for querying on multiple rowkeys.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, you want to do a column slice on multiple row keys at the same time.  The only thing I can think of is if you want to do a column slice on 100 rows is that you could use astyanax to do an 100 async queries(column slice) and then loop over the future such that all column slices are done at the same time anyways ;).  no need to have one api call when you have asynch apis.

We use something similar for a non-contiguous get when PlayOrm does a join with it's Scalable-SQL and it's fast.

later,
Dean

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can we use both hector and  astyanax  side by side

Answer (score 0):

There is no iterator for what you need. You'll have to code all the heavy lifting. . Something like this (assuming all strings):

```
MultigetSliceQuery<String, String, String> query = HFactory.createMultigetSliceQuery(keyspace, StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get()());
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
// add my keys
query.setColumnFamily("my cf").setKeys(keys).setRange(startColumn, endColumn, false, count);
// can also use setColumnNames(...) instead of setRange() to get specific columns
Rows<String,String,String> resultRows = query.execute().get();
for (Row<String, String, String> row : resultRows) {
   for (HColumn<String, ByteBuffer> col: row.getColumnSlice().getColumns()) {
      System.out.println("  " + col.getName() + ":" + col.getValue());
   }
}
```

If you have a very large number columns, It gets tricky because might have to iterate each row getting all the columns.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This is the traditional way of reading the data from MultiGetSliceQuery. But I am looking for ColumnSlice iterator (pagination)  in MultiGetSliceQuery

Comment: Right, there is not currently an iterator for what you need. But the source for ColumnSliceIterator is pretty simple and you can probably make your own ColumnMultiSliceIterator using ColumnSliceIterator as a template and adding code similar to above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result but it gives it row key wise,
i.e. 1st row key its column name/value
     2nd row key its column name/value

here the columns names I got at the end is time stamp values
and the column values are plain strings

I want to sort columns names irrespective of row keys...is there any facility to do so in cassandra... (i am making wall kind of functionality)

Comment: this is my question to all